# How to get current hosting address without Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Collector service which receives information via RabbitMQ about all currently running services - service name and host address. And now I need to implement Sender-part in each WebApi service I have. I don't want to make this sender class a controller, because I want to send info to Collector by raising an event each minute and because of that I can't use Request.RequestUri... and so on. Now it works manually - by calling Get method that gets host address and sends a message (raises an event). So, I need somehow make my code to know about where is it hosted. Is there any way of doing that?

And if there isn't, what if a best practice of solving this problem by using Request? Because I need a hostname to send a request that gets hostname... makes no sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Would just getting the IP address work for you?

Comment: I need  tad more details before I get into this honestly. You said you have a `Collector` service. Is this service a web api app too since you mentioned you dont want to make this guy a `Controller`?

Comment: @SwagataPrateek Yes, it is also web api app.

Comment: @sachin I don't think so.

Comment: @SwagataPrateek I've just figured out that my initial post was realy hard to understand. Maybe it is clearer now what is going on there.

Comment: Okay, so I see you have a couple of web api services that serves api payloads, you have a RabbitMq in the mix who expects a message on the server status and it collects data through a topic/queue and puts it in proper places.

Now you want to know, how can you invoke these events from these web services to the RabbitMQ and in the process to your Collector service automatically. Did I understand it right?

Comment: @SwagataPrateek Yep. Particularly I want to know how to get host address in that events.

Comment: Okay, two questions

1. Do you want to invoke these events 'automatically' from your web services in a periodic manner?
2. What does host address points to here? Client address or the actual address where the respective web service is hosted? Do you need ip address or actual hostname?

Comment: @SwagataPrateek 1. Yes. Going to use Timer class, I guess. 2.actual hostname, sth like `http://blabla.lala.hi:123/`

Comment: @AlexeyKoptyaev so, all of these web services are actual `Windows Services` or `self hosted` so that they have their own process allocated to them all of the time I presume, otherwise that timer thing would fail.

Comment: @SwagataPrateek self hosted, and they could be hosted on separate machines.

Comment: Sounds about right, be back with this later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my question here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2011/01/21/get-iis-bindings-at-runtime-without-being-an-administrator/

`bindings` section contains exactly what I needed to get.